# Javascript - Accessing variables inside function from window scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Please refer the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0ra0x50q/1/

Requirement is to access the variables inside the function from window scope. Either using closure or any other way.

```
function a() {
var x = 3;
this.y = 4;
}

alert(x) //should alert 3
alert(y) //should alert 4;
```

Note - You cannot store the values inside a new object and return it, or return the variables itself, in short no funny stuff!

Comment: You should be more precise on what you want. What is the usage of that function? Explain more.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi - Like I said, access the variables inside the function form window scope. Make a call to the function and thats it access it, but how is the q. There is not 1 more details for this question

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy is not healthy. You should change your scenario to avoid being in need of a variable declared locally, required globally, if you can.

But here is the solution:

```
function declareVariables()
{
   window.$config = "MyConfigValue"; // note you can use array, it's better.
}

declareVariables();
```

And then you can use:

```
console.log($config);
```